# Why Auto Implemented Properties Hidden Private Variable don't work when we have get or set?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public ReadOnly Property LazyLoadingMarket As MarketPairInanExchange
    Get
        _LazyLoadingMarket = Nothing
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property
```

Basically, I got a statement saying that _LazyLoadingMarket don't exist. That can easily be fixed by adding

Private _LazyLoadingMarket

But why doesn't it work if we have get statement? Took me a while to figure out that the Get statement makes the hidden private variable disappear.

Comment: Because if you have a getter/setter, you're responsible for creating the custom logic for the property (which might not even need a backing field). The automatically-generated backing field is something that belongs to auto-implemented properties. If you're not using an auto-implemented property, you opt-out of the "hidden magic" that comes with it.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties#backing-field): _"**When you declare an auto-implemented property**, Visual Basic automatically creates a hidden private field called the backing field to contain the property value"_.

Comment: None of us here are the designer, but I would hypothesize that they thought that if you are overriding the automatic bits, it's safest to not provide the hidden backing field because you may not want to have the property backed by a field at all.  The main exception in my experience has been with `INotifyPropertyChanged` where I want to add a notify on the setter but otherwise have it be the same as auto-implemented.